# IE9 reporting "Virtual Storage Mount Notification" add-on from "EldoS Corporation" is ready for use. Where from and can I trust it?

Tags: security, internet-explorer-9

I usually use Firefox to browse the web when I'm using my Windows 7 computer, but today I had a need to use Internet Explorer 9.  When I launched IE9 – for the first time in a while – I spotted a notification message at the bottom of my browser window that looked something like the following:

> The **"Virtual Storage Mount Notification"** add-on from **"EldoS Corporation"** is ready for use.
>   [Enable] [Disable]

If I had been using IE9 regularly, I might have understood exactly what software I had just installed that uses this 3rd party component, and been able to trust it by proxy of the trust I place in the vendor of the software I installed.

However, it had been months since my last use of IE9 and I can't remember what I might have installed in the meanwhile that could use something like this.  Considering this component was **brought to my attention** by IE9, I am rightly concerned about it.

So, I'd like to understand:

- what software might have installed this,
- what it is used for,
- is it trustworthy, and
- why is IE9 warning me about it?

I found [this other thread at Microsoft TechNet](http://qa.social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieitprocurrentver/thread/fb11a4ca-4481-4bc7-96c4-934b3747bfb2), but the responses are unhelpful.  The person that posted the answer (marked as accepted by Microsoft) is an employee of EldoS and may not be able to reveal the names of customers or the names of products from their customers .. so I understand the lack of direct helpfulness there.  At the same time, nobody from Microsoft stepped in to say "yeah, part of IE9 uses that, don't worry about it", so I'm assuming it comes from outside software I installed.

Short of uninstalling and re-installing everything on my computer and closely monitoring at each step, how else can I determine the origin, purpose, and safety of this component?  Even if this component itself is trustworthy, there's a possibility it could have been installed and used by some untrusted malware, right?  So I want to know.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A recent post found about this problem from [here](http://forums.techarena.in/technology-internet/1459218.htm).

> The Eldos Corporation is under notice for the add-on that they have
> added in Internet Explorer 9.  They have been sent a notice to provide
> the manual or instructions about the add-on. The add-on is no security
> threat and has shown good integration with other components of IE 9.
>
> This add-on notifies Internet Explorer about the content that has to
> be stored in virtual storage of the browser. This add-on is used by
> many other softwares too. It is a minor bug that IE 9 doesn’t hide the
> prompts regarding it.

**Update :-** I've searched it through their FAQ and found how to disable the notification )

Please try these,
It is a helper module for notification ,we cannot uninstall but can be disabled.

Start->run->type "regedit"-> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer\Browser Helper Objects{5FF49FE8-B332-4CB9-B102-FB6951629E55}

Hope this will help you :)

For more information read [this article](http://www.eldos.com/cbfs/articles/7595.php?sphrase_id=392259)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but were you quoting this? http://forums.techarena.in/technology-internet/1459218.htm  ... It's proper to include attribution when you quote or re-post content from elsewhere, not just copy/paste verbatim.

Comment: i was about to edit and and tried to share link , but miss-clicked submit button by mistake .Will edit it now .Thanks for that.

Comment: Thanks.  Doesn't really answer most of my question, but it's a start.